# Passing Struct Error "unqualified-id before '=' token"

Tags: c++, structure

I have been trying to pass a struct, which hold all my vars, to multiple functions, which are saved in a separate class. I know the error has to do with some sort of syntax error, most likely, but I do not see what I have done wrong.

The main.ccp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include "running.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //------Class Objects---------
    running runObj;

    //----------Vars--------------

    char saveGame = 'N';
    struct gameVar
    {
        int correctGuesses;  // These vars need to be reset for each new game.
        int Lives;
        int rowCorrect;
        int highScore;
        char anotherGame;
    } values;
    values.highScore = 12;
    values.anotherGame = 'Y';

    //--------Game Loop-----------

    // int highScore2 = runObj.readHighScore();


    while (values.anotherGame = 'Y')
    {
        struct gameVar = runObj.processGame(gameVar);
        struct gameVar = runObj.afterText(gameVar);
        gameVar values;
        values.anotherGame;
    }


    cout << endl << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to save your high score? Y/N" << endl;
    cin >> saveGame;

    if(saveGame == 'Y')
    {
        runObj.saveHighScore(gameVar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My header file is:

```
#ifndef RUNNING_H
#define RUNNING_H


class running
{
    public:
        struct gameVar processGame(struct gameVar);
        void saveHighScore(struct hs);
        int readHighScore();
        struct gameVar afterText(struct gameVar);
};

#endif // RUNNING_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a simple issue: you are using `=` in your `while` loop condition, which will assign the value `'Y'` to `gameVar.anotherGame`. What you actually want is `==`, to test for equality.

Take a look at this line:

```
struct gameVar = runObj.processGame(gameVar);
```

What are you trying to do here? `gameVar` is the name of your struct, not an object of `gameVar` type. Your object is actually called `values`. Perhaps you were wanting to do something like:

```
values = runObj.processGame(values);
```

Ditto for the next line too.

It seems like the reason you have this confusion is because you're defining your `struct` at the same time as creating an object of that type. The `struct` called `gameVar` is just a blueprint for objects and you create an object that matches that blueprint called `values`:

```
struct gameVar
{
  // ...
} values;
```

You might be less confused if you define the `struct` outside the `main` function as:

```
struct gameVar
{
  // ...
};
```

And then create the instance of it in `main` with:

```
gameVar values;
```

It is this `values` object that you must pass to a function - you can't pass a type, which is what `gameVar` is.

I'm not sure what you were then attempting to do with:

```
gameVar values;
values.anotherGame;
```

This would *redefine* the `values` object within the `while` loop and it will be destroyed at the end of the loop. You then access the data member `anotherGame` but don't do anything with it. Maybe you're looking for:

```
gameVar values;
values.highScore = 12;
values.anotherGame = 'Y';

while (values.anotherGame == 'Y')
{
    values = runObj.processGame(values);
    values = runObj.afterText(values);
}
```

It's worth noting that in C++, you do not need to put `struct` before every use of the `gameVar` type. The type name is just `gameVar`. That is, you could change your declaration of `processGame` to: `gameVar processGame(gameVar);`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think that I have a firmer grasp on structures now, and Now have the structures working. Thank you again!